# Intellij Ctrl-click on a class and it shows contents where the old class was?

Tags: intellij-idea

This is nuts. When I Ctrl-click on a class to see what is going on in that class, the contents I'm looking at vanish and the (new) class's contents appear.

So let's say I have one class (window) open. I Ctrl-click on an interesting looking object in that class, and instead of that class being shown in a new window-tab thing, it just is shown in my existing window-tab!

This is unexpected, even more so as I cannot Ctrl-Alt left back, because that makes my laptop change the total orientation of the screen (which I also do not understand).

What makes a Ctrl-click always open a new window pane?

Comment: have you tried removing your idea settings folder to see if that would reset this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might have IntelliJ setup to reuse tabs.
Go under Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs and make sure the "Navigation from non-modified tab will reuse it" setting is unchecked.
For some reason with this setting enabled IntelliJ will reuse which ever tab you are currently in if it has not been modified under VCS, even if you are not at your "tab limit".

[image: view setting]

---

Your <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> issue is an OS/graphics setting. I know Intel "HD" graphics has it enabled by default (and possibly some dedicated cards too), and you should be able to turn it off from the graphics control panel. (Or you can change the IntelliJ keyboard shortcut in the key mapper).